# How to manage the changing paragraph size in responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a page where there will be a simple content on the left side and an image on its right side. There will be another content whose background is colored just below the main content. The bottom of the image which is to the right side of the main content should be overlapped with the content which is below. Please take a look at the image below. That is the layout that I need.[image: Here's the layout that I neeed]

```css
.non-colored-content{
  width : 350px;
}
.colored-content{
  background-color: #0090FF;
  color : white;
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px black;
}
.main{
  background-image: url('http://www.abaarsoschool.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Abaarso-Simple-Logo-100x100.png');
  background-size : 45%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position : right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p class="non-colored-content">Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>
  <p class="colored-content">Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus..</p>
</div>
```

Here comes my problem. I somehow made the colored content to be overlapped on the bottom of the image. However, in the responsive screens whenever the browser size is changing the main non colored content's paragraph is getting increased and hence because of that the colored content is going far away from the image. Is there a way to either control the paragraph's size or stick my colored content on the bottom of the image? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can write a media query and control the same...but how do you want them to look like ,can be more clear here

Comment: I did try to use media queries but that's where I'm getting problem. Sorry for not being so clear. As I said, the colored content should overlap over the right image, That means the right image's bottom part should be on the backside of the colored content even in responsive screens @Geeky

Comment: The colored content is aligned is such that it is coming below the main content, hence whenever the main content's size changes the colored content's position is also getting changed. @Geeky

Answer (score 2):

Use display:flex and you can achieve the same and flex is responsive too

position:absolute/relative/fixed does not go well with responsive ness
check this snippet

```css
.non-colored-content {
  width: 350px;
}
.colored-content {
  background-color: #0090FF;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px black;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url('http://www.abaarsoschool.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Abaarso-Simple-Logo-100x100.png');
  background-size: 45%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p class="non-colored-content">Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
    in, elementum id enim. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
    in, elementum id enim. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>
  <p class="colored-content">Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
    in, elementum id enim. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus..</p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using bootstrap columns for the div's content. does this flex work if I use Bootstrap Col's? @Geeky

Comment: I dont think it will be a problem ..you can use display:flex with bootstrap too

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. Will let you know once it works :)

Comment: Felxbox is really good as it aligns elements properly, however the main problem that I'm facing is as the main content's size gets increased the colored content is pushed down more and more even after using the Flexbox.  @geeky

Comment: Then i think it is overriding with bootstrap columns...This link could be helpful to you https://codepen.io/morganfeeney/post/dont-build-bootstrap-style-grid-systems-with-flexbox...Im sorry but bootstrap columns and flexbox does not go together,may you should consider changing your design

Comment: I see, that's fine. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @ media rule to achieve responsive content on your page.

@media rule is used in CSS or you can use it as inline css.

Here is the reference link. It may help you in understanding @media rule.

```
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/
```